# How to build single page site from Markdown?

Tags: hugo

> Hugo is for people building a blog, company site, portfolio, tumblog, documentation, **single page site** or a site with thousands of pages.

http://gohugo.io/overview/introduction/

I'd like to make a single page site. My content is written in Markdown `index.md`. How do I build it?

It's necessary to build with Hugo (rather than pandoc) because I want to use its csv templating feature http://gohugo.io/extras/dynamiccontent/

---

I tried `hugo new` to create a blank site. If I create `_layouts/index.html` then `hugo server` will show that. But I want to write content in *Markdown*.

Comment: Hugo isn't a web app.  You run it locally (Windows, Mac, Linux) and it builds a website.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Hugo 0.18, this is now possible by creating a `content/_index.md` file, if the theme you are using supports it. You can create this file with the command `hugo new _index.md`. See the [Hugo docs](https://gohugo.io/content-management/organization/#index-pages-_indexmd) for more details.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for sharing

Comment: How do I know if the theme supports it?

Comment: @dash2 Often it will mention _index.md in the theme's documentation. If it doesn't you can always try the theme out using `hugo server -t <theme_name>` ([docs](https://gohugo.io/commands/hugo_server/)) and see if the content in _index.md shows up in the site. (You will need to download the theme to your themes directory in order for this to work.)

Answer (score 2):

Just write a post `example.md` as usual, Hugo will build it `public/example/index.html`. Then rather than push `public` to your web host, publish `public/example`. Voila, single page site.

Answer (score 1):

[the hugo quickstart](http://gohugo.io/overview/quickstart/) should have everything you need to get started, including adding markdown posts.  Specifically, `hugo new POSTNAME.md` will create a markdown post with proper header at `content/POSTNAME.md`.